# Get the last visited pages of a User of our ASP.NET Site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible get the last visited pages by user using C# / ASP.NET (without using javascript)

Comment: Wouldn't this be an invasion of the user's privacy?

Comment: Yes, but if you're using the internet, you have to consider that all your steps already are tracked. Ebay is a great example of that.

Comment: Ok, so you're talking about tracking the user through your site, right?

Comment: I'll ask a new question more clearly. Tks John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get in some cases the page from which the user came with [Referer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx).

Comment: Note that referrer is not reliable. It is an optional header, not always sent.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for. This'll add the last page's url to a string.

[ C# ]

```
string MyReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

[ VB.NET ]

```
Dim MyReferrer As String = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

The last visited pages on your site: Yes, you can keep track of that.
Last visited pages anywhere: No, common browsers do not send this information (except maybe the last url as referer header) to the server and therefore it's not available in your asp.net application.

Comment: How would you keep track of last visited pages on your site. Maybe that's what he wants to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cookie help to find latest visited page. Each and every page load event u can overwrite the cookie value but its not good for performance. Referrer is the best option to use this case.